# How to pass values from javascript to controller

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to pass the *id* and the *value* of some *textboxes* from the *view* to the *controller*. The *ajax* call works, but the value that it pass is always *Null*. How can i solve this problem??

This is the *ajax* call:

```
function TakeInput() {
    var count = document.getElementsByTagName('input').length;
    var element = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("Input", "Home")',
            data: JSON.stringify(element[i].id, element[i].value),
            processData: false,
            success: function () {
                //make something
            },
            error: function (errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        })
        }
```

And this is the controller:

```
public JsonResult Input(string id, string value)
        {
            //do something with the id and the value
            return Json(new { result = "Success" });
        }
```

Thanks in advance for your time and your answers.

Comment: Change it to: `data: { id: element[i].id, value: element[i].value }`

Comment: Your action can be of type `IActionResult` instead of `JsonResult`. Your action should be decorated with the `[HttpPost]` attribute.

Comment: I don't think `JSON.stringify(element[i].id, element[i].value)` does what you think it does.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looping the ajax call ,you can bind an object and pass it to controller then you can iterate it in server side. Whatever according to your code you can try the below one

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("Input", "Home")',
        data: JSON.stringify({ id: element[i].id, value: element[i].value}),
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function () {
            //make something
        },
        error: function (errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    })
```

When you are making an ajax call you need to declare the parameter like you declared in your **json result**  for example **id,value** etc and bind it into **data** attribute